# MUI React - unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I"m working on Fixed Bottom Navigation component using Material UI React , getting unexpected token error , it is pointing to **as** & throwing SyntaxError **Unexpected token, expected "," (93:21)** what should i change it to , what i have missed ? Please help. Also would like to map hardcode **const messageExamples**. I tried few things with that the messages are not refreshing when click on icons. Please help

```js
function refreshMessages() {
    const getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));

    return Array.from(new Array(50)).map(
        () => messageExamples[getRandomInt(messageExamples.length)],
    );
}

export const FixedBottomNavigations = ({ data, }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    const ref = React.useRef(null);
    const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState(() => refreshMessages());

    React.useEffect(() => {
        ref.current.ownerDocument.body.scrollTop = 0;
        setMessages(refreshMessages());
    }, [value, setMessages]);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
            <Box sx={{ pb: 7 }} ref={ref}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <List>
                    {data.map(({ primary, secondary, person }, index) => (
                        <ListItem button key={index + person}>
                            <ListItemAvatar>
                                <Avatar alt="Profile Picture" src={person} />
                            </ListItemAvatar>
                            <ListItemText primary={primary} secondary={secondary} />
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
                <Paper sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} elevation={3}>
                    <BottomNavigation
                        showLabels
                        value={value}
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                            setValue(newValue);
                        }}
                    >
                        <BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<RestoreIcon />} />
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Archive" icon={<ArchiveIcon />} />
                    </BottomNavigation>
                </Paper>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

const messageExamples = [
    {
        primary: 'Brunch this week?',
        secondary: "I'll be in the neighbourhood this week. Let's grab a bite to eat",
        person: '/static/images/avatar/5.jpg',
    },
    {
        primary: 'Birthday Gift',
        secondary: `Do you have a suggestion for a good present for John on his work
        anniversary. I am really confused & would love your thoughts on it.`,
        person: '/static/images/avatar/1.jpg',
    },

];


stories.js
export const FixedBottomNavigation = FixedBottomNavigations.bind({});
data: [
        {
            primary: 'Brunch this week?',
            secondary: "I'll be in the neighbourhood this week. Let's grab a bite to eat",
            person: '/static/images/avatar/5.jpg',
        },
        {
            primary: 'Birthday Gift',
            secondary: `Do you have a suggestion for a good present for John on his work
        anniversary. I am really confused & would love your thoughts on it.`,
            person: '/static/images/avatar/1.jpg',
        },
        ]
```

Comment: You have already defined that the ref will be a HTMLDivElement. Replace the line in the useEffect
```ref.current?.ownerDocument.body.scrollTop = 0;```

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves after adding above line , getting this error Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression.

Comment: This should work out ` if (scrollRef.current) {
        scrollRef.current.ownerDocument.body.scrollTop = 0;
    } `

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves no luck :( , the above code is also not working. Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet is saying `missing { before function body` on line twelve, maybe try changing `const ref = React.useRef < HTMLDivElement > (null);` to `const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);`?

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves 's first comment is the correct syntax to use. (`ref.current?.owner...`). Update your question to use that, and then update the code exactly with the exact syntax error.

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves updated code & error after adding 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

An approach for this problem could be this, to check if there is any current ref, if not return, else continue.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!ref.current) return;
  ref.current.ownerDocument.body.scrollTop = 0;
  setMessages(refreshMessages());
}, [value, setMessages]);
```

Comment: with this i'm getting error **Missing initializer in const declaration. (140:31)
**. it is pointing to **readonly**

Comment: I do not think that has something to do with the `ref` issue. It seems like you need to update your readonly interface, I found [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/14/typescript-readonly-intro/) which you might find usefull

Comment: Thanks for your answers . Any idea on how to get messages dynamic ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get messages dynamic" ?

Comment: **const messageExamples ** is there any way to map hardcode content.

Comment: You are already mapping over your messageExamples right? If you want to map only over the messageExamples you can just const [messages, ...] = React.useState(messageExamples)

Comment: yes, but with that messages are not refreshing on click of icons. i have updated my code. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248900/discussion-between-rubensmn-and-advi).